# Ruby How to display message if include? statement is true or false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, include

I'm **very** new to Ruby and am attempting to display one of two messages based on whether certain words are included in an array. My current controller contains the following:

```
@cookie = ["gluten", "sugar", "dairy", "chocolate"]
```

And my view contains this:

```
<%= @cookie.include?"gluten" %>
```

The above returns 'true' and prints on the page just fine. However, nothing gets printed on the page when trying either of the following methods. The page renders fine with no errors, but no messages:

```
<%= puts "Sorry" if @cookie.include?"gluten" %>
```

and

```
<%= 
if @cookie.include?("gluten")
  puts "Sorry, you cannot eat this."
    else
  puts "You have the greenlight."
    end
%>
```

I'm hoping that I'm creating a very simple mistake in syntax or am misunderstanding the usage of the include? function.

Comment: <% if @cookie.include?("gluten") %> Sorry <% else %> Greenlight <% end %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at the ruby it appears to be sound, http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/d6798.

Must be  rails error so try

```
<% if @cookie.include?("gluten") %>
  <%= "Sorry, you cannot eat this." %>
<%  else %>
  <%= "You have the greenlight." %>
<%  end %>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Without knowing the full gamut of my code/installation do you have any idea why I'd experience rails errors like that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it all in one erb statement, you would do something like this:

Don't use "puts". The "<%=" is already doing a 'to_s' and will output the value to the response body.  You may have seen the results show up in your logs if you used 'puts'.

Also - for erb, the <% ... %> syntax, that is for logic, often an 'each' or 'if' state, the <%= %> is for writing to the screen.  Most of the time it is the attribute of a ruby object like <%= user.name %>

Comment: This will be helpful in the future! Thanks so much!